# How to add data from forecast dataframe to another dataframe so it can be plotted

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, forecasting

New guy here with another likely stupid question. I'm using the forecast Library to produce forecast dataframes based on several variables I have in another dataframe. Now I want to add rows to my original dataframe with the forecasts. Ideally, I want forecast data in new columns so the appearance can be different when plotted (I'm using ggplot2 if that makes a difference). I originally tried the geom_forecast() function which I found to be completely useless, but maybe that's just my inexperience.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

ETA The data looks like this

```
df_data <- data.frame("date" = c(as.Date("2021-03-05") - 0:35), "var1" = c(NA, NA, NA, 0.04408070, 0.04422306, 0.04460695, 0.04532817, 0.04602877, 0.04674434, 0.04752608, 0.04828689, 0.04910968, 0.05006677, 0.05102092, 0.05237367, 0.05300535, 0.05322645, 0.05454669, 0.05696812, 0.05860335, 0.05991309, 0.06093534, 0.06195960, 0.06351324, 0.06489379, 0.06568839, 0.06681679, 0.06866297, 0.07080985, 0.07217151, 0.07294732, 0.07450025, 0.07681193, 0.07929639, 0.08152944, 0.08349083), "var2" = c(NA, NA, NA, 890393.0000, 1024662.5714, 1115569.2857, 1172178.7143, 1211248.7143, 1230645.5714, 1239683.1429, 1238111.8571, 1226921.2857, 1201435.5714, 1174988.7143, 1120524.8571, 1088202.8571, 1084565.5714, 1091217.1429, 1099910.8571, 1103150.0000, 1125253.7143, 1188580.7143, 1224574.4286, 1248414.7143, 1283050.2857, 1342914.0000, 1416645.5714, 1452003.2857, 1445888.4286, 1446316.5714, 1462926.5714, 1475569.2857, 1474624.0000, 1469220.1429, 1496057.2857, 1516546.2857))
```

ETA2 This is the code I used to create the forecasts and the plots I want to add the projections to

```
var1_ts <- ts(df_data$var1[36:4], start = min(df_data$date), end = max(df_data$date)- 3, frequency = 1)
df_forecast_var1 <- as.data.frame(holt(var1_ts, h = 17))

var2_ts <- ts(df_data$var2[36:4], start = min(df_data$date), end = max(df_data$date)- 3, frequency = 1)
df_forecast_var2 <- as.data.frame(forecast::forecast(auto.arima(var2_ts), h = 17))


p1 <- ggplot(df_data, aes(date, var1)) + geom_line(color = "magenta", size = 1) 
p2 <- ggplot(df_data, aes(date, var2)) + geom_line(color = "green", size = 1)
```

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve] - Thank you.

Comment: @Uwe I've added what my data looks like

Comment: @Uwe updated again so people could actually reproduce the data. Sorry. As I said I'm new, I will do better.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide the data in such a way that one can create a data frame with it. I'm not willing to hand type your data.

Generally speaking, you can add your forecasts as new rows to your data, but as of now they do not have the same time format as your training data. There is a new forecast package called [fable](https://github.com/tidyverts/fable) which makes this data wrangling for time series forecasts a lot easier.

If you provide the data in a more usable way I'll update my answer to show how to achieve your desired results with your preexisting code.

I write this as answer, because I have not enough reputation to comment.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason why `forecast::geom_forecast()` gave unsatisfactory results is because the `date` vector is reversed, running from `2021-03-05` backwards in time to `2021-01-29`:

```
df_data <- data.frame("date" = c(as.Date("2021-03-05") - 0:35), "var1" = c(NA, NA, NA, 0.04408070, 0.04422306,
```

To fix this, you can either use `date = as.Date("2021-03-05") - 35:0` when creating `df_data` or reverse the order of rows in the existing data.frame `df_data` by

```
df_rev <- df_data[nrow(df_data):1, ]
```

Now, `geom_forcast()` gives reasonable looking results, at least to me:

```
library(forecast)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df_rev, aes(date, var1)) + 
  geom_line(color = "magenta", size = 1) +
  geom_forecast(model = holt, h = 17)
```

[image]

```
ggplot(df_rev, aes(date, var2)) + 
  geom_line(color = "green", size = 1) +
  geom_forecast(model = auto.arima, h = 17)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it was the date order that was making geom_forecast act weird. I do have a few follow-up Qs (If a separate Q is more appropriate let me know) 1) is there a way to constrain the forecast to just positive numbers? 2) I tried removing the confidence intervals using the argument PI = FALSE, but it didn't work and caused the plot to fail. 3) geom_forecast doesn't seem to recognize the argument "model" so I can't check how different models look. 4) can the point values for the forecasts be extracted?

Comment: @Drewnonymous, I am afraid the additional questions are beyond my scope of knowledge. Therefore, I kindly suggest that you may either search SO for already existing answers or post a new question for each of your points. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you anyway! I'm just at the start of my journey learning R and appreciate the reply.